# Android Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_PICK_IMAGES) doesn't display users folders

Tags: android, android-13

I am using the new Android 13 API to pick images + videos from user's gallery. However the UI displayed when calling the new API doesn't let me browser through the folders I have created in my device gallery. I can only see recent media... Which is a mess to scroll in... Did I miss something in my code ?

```
int requestCode;
Intent libraryIntent;
requestCode = REQUEST_LAUNCH_LIBRARY;
libraryIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_PICK_IMAGES);
libraryIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_PICK_IMAGES_MAX, 5);
libraryIntent.putExtra("forceShowBrowse", true);
libraryIntent.setType("*/*");
libraryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[]{"image/*", "video/*"});
currentActivity.startActivityForResult(libraryIntent, requestCode);
```

Only recents here

[image]

And useless folders here
[image]